# how does one deal with x must be numeric error in correlation plot?

Tags: r, correlation

Im trying to produce a correlation plot for my data but i get 'x must be numeric error', other fixes have not worked for my case. Do i have to change the month to numeric as well? or is there a way of selecting only the numeric columns for my plot

Tried converting all to numeric but it just changes back to factor automatically

```
getwd()
myDF <- read.csv("qbase.csv")
head(myDF)
str(myDF)

cp <-cor(myDF)
head(round(cp,2))

'data.frame':   12 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Month                    : Factor w/ 12 levels "18-Apr","18-Aug",..: 5 4 8 1 9 7 6 2 12 11 ...
 $ Monthly.Recurring.Revenue: Factor w/ 2 levels "$25,000 ","$40,000 ": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Price.per.Seat           : Factor w/ 2 levels "$40 ","$50 ": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Paid.Seats               : int  500 500 500 500 500 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 ...
 $ Active.Users             : int  10 50 50 100 450 550 800 900 950 800 ...
 $ Support.Cases            : int  0 0 1 5 35 155 100 75 50 45 ...
 $ Users.Trained            : int  1 5 0 50 100 300 50 30 0 100 ...
 $ Features.Used            : int  5 5 5 5 8 9 9 10 15 15 ...
```

The results to `dput(myDF)` as are follows:

> `dput( myDF)`

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("18-Apr", "18-Aug", "18-Dec", 
"18-Feb", "18-Jan", "18-Jul", "18-Jun", "18-Mar", "18-May", "18-Nov", 
"18-Oct", "18-Sep"), class = "factor"), Monthly.Recurring.Revenue = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("$25,000 ", 
"$40,000 "), class = "factor"), Price.per.Seat = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("$40 ", 
"$50 "), class = "factor"), Paid.Seats = c(500L, 500L, 500L, 
500L, 500L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L), 
    Active.Users = c(10L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 450L, 550L, 800L, 900L, 
    950L, 800L, 700L, 600L), Support.Cases = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 
    35L, 155L, 100L, 75L, 50L, 45L, 10L, 5L), Users.Trained = c(1L, 
    5L, 0L, 50L, 100L, 300L, 50L, 30L, 0L, 100L, 50L, 0L), Features.Used = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: You have multiple answers, several of which are claiming to remove an error because their code does not say "Error" when run. But how many of them are actually changing the values to be valid months? None f them I suspect. If you turn a factor value into numeric without a proper converstion to Date class then April and Augus will both be lower than January. Better answers might come if you posted the output of `dput(  myDF)`. You should do this with the original version. Not the one after the code below has been applied.

Comment: @42- Thanks a lot for the tips, i'm completely new to this thats why my posting of comments and code is a bit off. i will repost the output of  `dput(myDF)`. In the end i intend to produce a correlation plot using `corrplot(myDF, method="circle")` and also run a multiple linear regression to see which variables affect active users the most. Any help with that will also be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert dates to `POSIXct` and also remove the dollar sign to convert the second and third columns to numeric:

```r
myDF$Month <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(myDF$Month, format="%d-%b", tz="GMT"))
myDF[,c(2,3)] <-  sapply(myDF[,c(2,3)], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[\\$,]", "", x)))

cp <-cor(myDF)

library(ggcorrplot)
ggcorrplot(cp)
```

Comment: Have you actually tested whether that format is acceptable to the as.POSIXct function. It certainly was NOT the last time I tried it.

Comment: @42- I actually tested it with `"18-Apr"`

Comment: @M-M appreciate the help, i still got the 'x must be numeric' error after running the first 3 lines of code.

Comment: @MarcusAnum well if you share output of `dput(head(myDF))` to your question it is possible to test the solutions and help you better.

Comment: @M-M You didn't throw an error but I think you made a semantic error, nonetheless. A column named "Month" with a vleu of "18-Apr" is more likely to be April, 2018 than it is to be the 18th of April, 2019.

Comment: @42- that's right but for the purpose of this question, is that important?

Comment: I assume the OP was hoping to get a valid answer rather than an invalid one.

Comment: @42- I am genuinely asking. Does year matter in terms of calculating correlation? If it does, I will edit my answer

Comment: @MarcusAnum First of all please add your code to the question instead of posting a comment. Second, the structure you posted is different from output of `str(myDF)`. It does not contain factors. In this structure, first column is POSIXct and others are numeric.

Comment: Yes it certailly does. The ordering of months will be wrong. factor variables are ordered alphabetically, not in the order in which they are present in the input vector. So April would be first, August second and December would be before January.

Comment: @42- Right. In any case, data that OP shared is totally different, but your point is taken.

Comment: Imagine a situation where this data layout and formatting spanned multiple years. Since the "year" value gets turned into the day of the month with your answer, you will be interleaving the year values.Yes. Invalid

Comment: @42- I understand, but that needs extra info.

Comment: The right way would have pasted a 01 for a day of month or to use as.yrmon from zoo package. Either of these would have needed to be done first.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a correlation between factors and numeric columns, wich can't happen (`cor` handles only numeric, hence the error). You can do:

```
library(data.table)

ir <- data.table(iris) # since you didn't produce a reproducible example

ir[, cor(.SD), .SDcols = names(ir)[(lapply(ir, class) == "numeric")]]
```

### what is in there:

`cor(.SD)` will calculate the correlation matrix for a new dataframe composed of a subset data.table (`.SD`, see `?data.table`).

`.SDcols` establish wich columns will go into that subset data.table. They are only those which class is `numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the dollar sign and change the integer variables to numeric using sapply, then calculate the correlation.

```
myDF[,c(2,3)] <-  sapply(myDF[,c(2,3)], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[\\$,]", "", x)))
newdf <-  sapply(myDF[,2:8],as.numeric)
cor(newdf)
```

Edited:

If you want to use the month variable. Please install lubridate and use month function.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)
myDF$Month<- month(as.POSIXct(myDF$Month, format="%d-%b", tz="GMT"))
myDF[,c(2,3)] <-  sapply(myDF[,c(2,3)], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[\\$,]", "", x)))
newdf <-  sapply(myDF,as.numeric)
cor(as.data.frame(newdf))
```

Comment: Highly likely this is wrong. Just because you eliminate an error is not sufficient to get code that is correct.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. any idea which type of regression would be best to check which variables are statistically significant to each other within this same data frame?

Comment: If you want to use the month variable, you can use package lubridate. And then, myDF$Month <- month(as.POSIXct(myDF$Month, format="%d-%b", tz="GMT"))

Comment: @RodrigoDíazLupanow thanks for the edit. when i try to get a correlation plot using:                                                                                                  
library(corrplot)
corrplot(myDF, method="circle") .                                                                             
i get the following error                                                                          corrplot(myDF, method="circle")
Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent.

Comment: Did you try with corrplot(as.dataframe(myDF))?

Comment: @RodrigoDíazLupanow corrplot takes 2 arguements corrplot(myDF, method='preffered method')

Comment: corrplot(as.dataframe(myDF), method="circle")

Comment: It worked, i was passing myDF all along but i was supposed to be passing newDF. thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert those months to Date class:

```
myDF$MonDt <- as.Date( paste0(myDF$Month, "-15"), format="%y-%b-%d")
```

Could also have used `zoo::as.yearmon`. Either method would allow you to apply `as.numeric` to get a valid time scaled value. The other answers are adequate when using single year data but because they incorrectly make the assumption the the leading two digits are day of the month rather than the year, they are going to fail to deliver valid answers in any multi-year dataset, but will not throw any warning about this.

```
with(myDF, cor(Active.Users, as.numeric(MonDt) )  )
[1] 0.8269705
```

As one of the other answers illustrated removing the $ and commas is needed before as.numeric will succeed on currency-formatted text. Again, this is also factor data so `as.numeric` could have yielded erroneous answers, although in this simple example it would not. A safe method would be:

```
myDF[2:3] <- lapply(myDF[2:3], function(x) as.numeric( gsub("[$,]", "", x)))

myDF
    Month Monthly.Recurring.Revenue Price.per.Seat Paid.Seats Active.Users
1  18-Jan                     25000             50        500           10
2  18-Feb                     25000             50        500           50
3  18-Mar                     25000             50        500           50
4  18-Apr                     25000             50        500          100
5  18-May                     25000             50        500          450
6  18-Jun                     40000             40       1000          550
7  18-Jul                     40000             40       1000          800
8  18-Aug                     40000             40       1000          900
9  18-Sep                     40000             40       1000          950
10 18-Oct                     40000             40       1000          800
11 18-Nov                     40000             40       1000          700
12 18-Dec                     40000             40       1000          600
   Support.Cases Users.Trained Features.Used      MonDt
1              0             1             5 2018-01-15
2              0             5             5 2018-02-15
3              1             0             5 2018-03-15
4              5            50             5 2018-04-15
5             35           100             8 2018-05-15
6            155           300             9 2018-06-15
7            100            50             9 2018-07-15
8             75            30            10 2018-08-15
9             50             0            15 2018-09-15
10            45           100            15 2018-10-15
11            10            50            15 2018-11-15
12             5             0            15 2018-12-15
```

This question gets an answer that allows multiple correlation coefficients to be calculated and the two way data associations plotted on one page:

[How to add p values for correlation coefficients plotted using splom in lattice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161954/how-to-add-p-values-for-correlation-coefficients-plotted-using-splom-in-lattice)